# SSB of Spacetime Symmetries in 2d

Tags: spacetime, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

Colemans theorem states that there are no Goldstone Bosons in $d=2$ spacetime dimensions : https://inspirehep.net/literature/83738 because there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking.

However I have read that for spacetime symmetries there can be a spontaneous symmetry breaking even in $d=2$ and thus Goldstone modes.

My question is:

Where in the proof of Colemans theorem does he assume the symmetry to be global or why does the proof not work for spacetime symmetries?

Comment: Can you cite where you read that Goldstone modes can appear in 2d theories with spontaneously broken spacetime symmetries?